# TreeMap$Entry trying to iterate on JSON array in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to iterate on a JSON array that could have a variation of different products.

Here is a possible sample JSON response:

```
[
    products:[
        appliance:[
            availableVersions:[
                [
                    firmware:wired-16-16-7, id:2379, releaseDate:2022-11-17T00:43:56Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MX 16.16.7
                ], 
                [
                    firmware:wired-17-10-2, id:2372, releaseDate:2022-10-26T20:43:56Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MX 17.10.2
                ], 
                [
                    firmware:wired-18-1-03, id:2376, releaseDate:2022-11-07T20:48:02Z, releaseType:beta, shortName:MX 18.103
                ]
            ], 
            currentVersion:[
                firmware:wired-16-16, id:2277, releaseDate:2022-02-28T17:22:52Z, releaseType:legacy, shortName:MX 16.16
            ], 
            lastUpgrade:[
            ], 
                fromVersion:[:], time:, toVersion:[:]
            nextUpgrade:[
                time:2023-01-29T03:06:00Z, toVersion:[
                    firmware:wired-17-10-2, id:2372, releaseDate:2022-10-26T20:43:56Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MX 17.10.2
                ]
            ], 
            participateInNextBetaRelease:false
        ], 
        camera:[
            availableVersions:[
                [
                    firmware:camera-4-18-1, id:2345, releaseDate:2022-07-18T18:10:33Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MV 4.18.1
                ], 
                [
                firmware:camera-5-0, id:2373, releaseDate:2022-11-01T17:14:57Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MV 5.0
                ]
            ], 
            currentVersion:[
                firmware:camera-4-18-1, id:2345, releaseDate:2022-07-18T18:10:33Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MV 4.18.1
            ], 
            lastUpgrade:[
                fromVersion:[:], time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            nextUpgrade:[
                time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            participateInNextBetaRelease:false
        ], 
        cellularGateway:[
            availableVersions:[
                [
                    firmware:Custom version (4926ea8), id:2178, releaseDate:2021-06-18T00:24:38Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MG 1.11
                ]
            ], 
            currentVersion:[
                firmware:Custom version (4926ea8), id:2178, releaseDate:2021-06-18T00:24:38Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MG 1.11
            ], 
            lastUpgrade:[
                fromVersion:[:], time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            nextUpgrade:[
                time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            participateInNextBetaRelease:false
        ], 
        sensor:[
            availableVersions:[
                [
                    firmware:Custom version (039f1a7), id:2290, releaseDate:2022-04-12T02:59:33Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MT 1.4
                ]
            ], 
            currentVersion:[
                firmware:Custom version (039f1a7), id:2290, releaseDate:2022-04-12T02:59:33Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MT 1.4
            ], 
            lastUpgrade:[
                fromVersion:[:], time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            nextUpgrade:[
                time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            participateInNextBetaRelease:false
        ], 
        switch:[
            availableVersions:[
                [
                    firmware:switch-14-33-1, id:2279, releaseDate:2022-03-15T14:40:38Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MS 14.33.1
                ], 
                [
                    firmware:switch-15-18, id:2380, releaseDate:2022-11-29T21:16:13Z, releaseType:candidate, shortName:MS 15.18
                ]
            ], 
            currentVersion:[
                firmware:switch-14-33-1, id:2279, releaseDate:2022-03-15T14:40:38Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MS 14.33.1
            ], 
            lastUpgrade:[
                fromVersion:[:], time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            nextUpgrade:[
                time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            participateInNextBetaRelease:false
        ], 
        wireless:[
            availableVersions:[
                [
                    firmware:wireless-29-4-1, id:2369, releaseDate:2022-10-14T18:32:32Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MR 29.4.1
                ], 
                [
                    firmware:wireless-29-5, id:2378, releaseDate:2022-11-14T18:10:38Z, releaseType:candidate, shortName:MR 29.5
                ]
            ], 
            currentVersion:[
                firmware:wireless-29-4-1, id:2369, releaseDate:2022-10-14T18:32:32Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:MR 29.4.1
            ], 
            lastUpgrade:[
                fromVersion:[:], time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            nextUpgrade:[
                time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            participateInNextBetaRelease:false
        ],
        systemsManager:[
            availableVersions:[
                [
                    firmware:Custom version (53c09c1), id:385, releaseDate:2006-08-04T22:06:00Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:SM 0.0
                ]
            ], 
            currentVersion:[
                firmware:Custom version (53c09c1), id:385, releaseDate:2006-08-04T22:06:00Z, releaseType:stable, shortName:SM 0.0
            ], 
            lastUpgrade:[
                fromVersion:[:], time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            nextUpgrade:[
                time:, toVersion:[:]
            ], 
            participateInNextBetaRelease:false
        ]
    ], 
    timezone:America/Los_Angeles, 
    upgradeWindow:[
        dayOfWeek:Sun, chourOfDay:3:00
    ]
]
```

I would like to iterate through whatever is returned under products, but when I try doing:

```
    networkFirmware.products.each { it ->
        println "${it} is: " + it

        if (it.appliance) {
            println "I matched APPLIANCE!!"
        }
    }
```

I get an error stating: exception:No such property: appliance for class: java.util.TreeMap$Entry.

I know I can access and iterate on the availableVersions if I point to networkFirmware.products.appliance (for example), but I would prefer to not have to hard code every possible product just to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`networkFirmware.products` is a `Map` so when you iterate over it you should be visiting `Map$Entry` instances.  In your `Closure` that will be what `it` references.  `it.key` should be the key in the `Map` and `it.value` should be the value.  `it.appliance` should be invalid because the `Map$Entry` instance does not contain a property named `appliance`.

Comment: Not seeing products as a map was the part I was overlooking. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: "Thanks for catching that!" - You are welcome.  I am glad that was helpful.